# Sage One Api error while requesting through php

Tags: php, api, integration, sage-erp, sage-one

I am using https://github.com/eddieharrison/sageone-api-php for connecting to Sage one. The problem is after accessing the token key when i use the service like say `get-ledger-accounts.php` with the current access token that i get from sage page everytime i get this error

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
Content-Type: application/json 
Date: Tue, 10 May 2016 11:50:57 GMT Server: openresty 
Content-Length: 114 
Connection: keep-alive

{
    "$diagnoses": [
        {
            "$severity": "error",
            "$dataCode": "AuthorizationFailure",
            "$message": "Access Denied",
            "$source": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

why is that ? Whereas if i use the refresh token key it gives an error for invalid key which is correct. Can someone help me on this

Comment: Are you able to show us the complete request header?

Comment: I have the same problem any ideas?